# How to hide and show and element as per input value in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

How to show and hide input as per sibling input value in vue js.

Comment: I hope this will help   [doc for you](https://dmitripavlutin.com/vue-show-hide-elements/#:~:text=Hiding%20using%20v%2Dshow,-Often%20it's%20useful&text=v%2Dshow%20deals%20with%20showing,still%20rendered%20in%20the%20DOM.)

Comment: what did you tried so far ? You can use `v-show` in the input and pass the sibling `v-model` value in it to check if it contains value or not.

Comment: As in your previously closed question, people expect you to show some code about what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `v-show` in the input and pass the sibling `v-model` value in it to check if it contains value or not.

In below demo, we are showing the input if sibling input have `alpha` value. You can add condition as per your requirement.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input1: null,
    input2: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="input1" placeholder="Input 1"/>
  <input type="text" v-show="input1 === 'alpha'" v-model="input2"  placeholder="Input 2"/>
</div>
```